# Other computer can't connect to MySQL Database

Tags: networking, mysql, wamp, vb.net

I have a VB .NET program the uses a MySQL database. It works when the computer that has WAMP installed is the one running the program.

The same program now displays an `Unhandled Exception` error when the computer it's running on does not have WAMP installed (and running). The only thing that is installed is the MySQL connecter net.

How can I make this work?

I have already tried opening port 20 by configuring the firewall. I did this for both TCP and UDP.

Comment: Is the port for mysql open? Do you have a firewall that is blocking the access? What does the exception say?

Comment: yeah port 80 is opened . the exception says that it cannot connect to the database

Answer (score 1):

It could be the mysql server has the networking restricted or turned off.

Search for the file `my.cnf` and look for any of the following lines in the file in the `[mysqld]` section.

```
skip-networking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

delete or comment out these lines and then restart mysqld.

FYI:  mysqld uses tcp port 3306 for client communication.